# How can you get the JSON Path?

Tags: java, json

Given a sample JSON:

```
{
  "hello" : "wolrd",
  "arrayField" : ["one", "two", "three"],
  "mapField" : {
    "name" : "john",
    "lastName" : "doe" 
  }
}
```

Is there a framework in Java to help me get the JSON path structure from the JSON tree? Something similar to this:

```
$.hello
$.arrayField[0]
$.arrayField[1]
$.arrayField[2]
$.mapField.name
$.mapField.lastName
```

**EDIT:**

I've already coded a first approach using fasterxml's Jackson.  But I'd like to know if there's something more robust / flexible.

```
   final JsonNode rootNode = mapper.readValue(jon, JsonNode.class);
    printFieldKeys(rootNode, "$");

    private static void printFieldKeys(JsonNode rootNode, String parent) {
        final Iterator<Entry<String, JsonNode>> fieldIt = rootNode.fields();
        while (fieldIt.hasNext()) {
            final Entry<String, JsonNode> next = fieldIt.next();
            final JsonNode value = next.getValue();
            final String path = parent + "." + next.getKey();

            if (value.isValueNode()) {
                System.out.println(path + " = " + value.asText());
            } else  {
                System.out.println(path);
            }


            if (value.isArray()) {
                for (int i = 0; i < value.size(); i++) {
                    printFieldKeys(value.get(i), path + "[" + i + "]");
                }
            } else {
                printFieldKeys(value, path);
            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: Use libraries like Jackson: http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-convert-java-object-to-from-json-jackson/

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at this library: https://github.com/jayway/JsonPath

I believe it does exactly what you want. :)

Comment: I looked at it and I think it has the capability to read and deserialize JSON by the provided Path string, but didn't find how to get the path of a given node in the structure.

Comment: Really? Reading the documentation I read that you can configure it to return the path of matched elements. Did you see that part of documentation: https://github.com/jayway/JsonPath#path-vs-value